# React Native - How to repeate a component in jsx through loop?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, loops, jsx

I am trying to create a for loop in jsx - react native, but I've failed. All soultion guide me to use `map`, but I don't have an array to loop throught inside it via `map`.

```
const num = 5;
```

I want a way to repeate a component (ex: Button) certain times (in this case 5 times).

```
<Button title="help" onPress={doSomething} />
```

Comment: Easy to do, but *why* do you need 5 of the same button component? Or is the "index" related to any expected output?

Answer (score 0):

`Array(5).fill()` will create an array of length 5 with `undefined` values, but you can then easily map it within JSX.

```js
const onClickHandler = index => () => console.log(`Button ${index} clicked`);

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    {Array(5).fill().map((_, index) => (
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={onClickHandler(index)}
      >
        Button {index}
      </button>
    ))}
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
const myArray = Array.from({length: 5}, (e, i) => i + 1);
```

to create a array with 5 element then you can loop it with

```
{myArray.map(item) => (<Button key={item} title="help" onPress={doSomething} />)}
```